# Does Baby Groot exist in the comics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2, groot

Just what it says:

Do Baby Groot and

> Teenage Groot

exist in the comics or were they invented at the end of the *Guardian of the Galaxy* movie for the MCU only?

## I AM GROOT!

<sup>I am Groot</sup>

Comment: [Apparently](http://i.imgur.com/ulJWsPW.jpg)

Comment: [Spider-Pig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Ham) existed in the comics 24 years before [the Simpsons movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BARjPuUN36Y), so I’m gonna guess yup.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You found this while searching for a baby Groot picture, huh? "FEMALE GROOT?! That's not a baby Groot!"

Comment: Of note, not an answer to the question, but [probably should be included in the answer](https://www.polygon.com/comics/2017/2/16/14637072/baby-groot-comic-book-guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2)

Comment: @ThePopMachine Nice!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Yes! Well, *soon*.

In May 2017, a brand new comic book titled [I am Groot](https://news.marvel.com/comics/64479/flaviano-declares-groot/) will be published.

[Marvel explains](https://comicstore.marvel.com/I-Am-Groot-2017/comics-series/91530):

> GROOT IN HIS OWN SERIES, SMALLER AND BETTER THAN EVER! When the Guardians of the Galaxy get caught in a wormhole, a smaller-than-normal Groot is separated billions of light-years away from the team. Falling to a planet below, Groot discovers he is on an entirely alien and unknown world full of strange creatures and societies. Seriously underdeveloped and with nobody who can understand him, Groot will need to make the journey to the center of this world and find the way back to his family!

[image]

[image]